# VB.NET Build Events isn't there

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Not much I can tell you, the build events button in Properties > Compile physically isn't there.

Comment: What? There isn't anything I _can_ tell you!

Comment: If you've seen it before then your machine got messed up, you'll need to fix it and reinstall VS.  If you never seen it before then you probably don't realize that you have to scroll the window to the right to see it.

Comment: @HansPassant I've never seen it before, but there isn't a scroll bar.

Comment: Which version of VS 2013 do you have?  Express, Premium, Ultimate?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment that you are using the express version, this is from the MSDN documentation:

> Visual Basic Express does not support entry of build events. This is supported only in the full Visual Studio product.

[MSDN Visual Studio 13 Documentation for Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xctbe2f.aspx)

Just as an added note, you *might* be able to edit your project file manually and add the build events. MSBuild might still use them.  I'm not sure about this point, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit build events in the project file.

1. Unload project (right click in Solution Explorer)
2. Then right click the project, and choose the object to edit the .vbproj file.

This will show you the XML of the project file.

3. Within the property group element, you can add elements for the events, for example